# Concurrent calls to onCheckedChanged

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have some checkboxes that share the same CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.

If the onCheckedChanged method takes a lot of time to complete, is it possible that two checkboxes clicked in rapid succession will cause the two onCheckedChanged callback methods to be interleaved?

Basically, I want to make sure that if checkboxes A, B, and C are clicked in that order, then the callback methods for A, B, and C are executed in that order with no interleaving.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> If the onCheckedChanged method takes a lot of time to complete

You should do operations that could take a bit longer in another Thread or async task, otherwise you would block the main thread and the UI might not beworking properly.

> is it possible that two checkboxes clicked in rapid succession will
>   cause the two onCheckedChanged callback methods to be interleaved

You will only be able to click the checkboxes in rapid succession when the main thread is not blocked by the first callback (see above)

> Basically, I want to make sure that if checkboxes A, B, and C are
>   clicked in that order, then the callback methods for A, B, and C are
>   executed in that order with no interleaving.

If you follow my suggestion and do longer work in a background thread/async task, then the order of the callbacks will be correct.